# Deep linking TYPO3, Siteimprove, LDAP / SSO Authentication

Tags: typo3

I am trying to link Siteimprove 1) with our TYPO3 website. This would make it possible to link directly from Siteimprove to broken links in TYPO3. This way the broken links could be found and repaired faster.

For this purpose, I installed EXT:pxa_siteimprove 2) in version 4.0.6.

In Siteimprove, links in the form https://www.domain.ch/typo3/index.php?redirect_url=/typo3/?tx_siteimprove_goto=page:160:0 are generated. When I click on this link, the TYPO3 backend login appears. After logging in, the standard backend display appears. If I now copy the URL into the same browser window and call it up, TYPO3 jumps to the right place.

It does not work in TYPO3 CMS 10.4 or 11.5. For the backend login we also use the EXT:ig_ldap_sso_auth 3)

Can the session be transferred from browser window to browser window?

1. https://www.siteimprove.com
2. https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/pxa_siteimprove
3. https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/ig_ldap_sso_auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a samesite cookie problem, the configuration depends on your setup

https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/8.7.x/Feature-90351-ConfigureTYPO3-shippedCookiesWithSameSiteFlag.html

Comment: $GLOBALS[TYPO3_CONF_VARS][BE][cookieSameSite] = "lax" solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no transferable login into TYPO3.

TYPO3 uses cookies and sessions for login. If you are logged in to a TYPO3 instance with a browser any new window with that browser to that instance will have the login status (keep watch: normal mode and privacy mode identify as different browsers and do not share any cookies).
You need one log in for your default browser. Any automatically opened links from any program will reuse the cookies from that browser window and can follow the link directly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour described in the combination of TYPO3 CMS 10 and EXT:ig_ldap_sso_auth that I use. The login is requested for every new window. In Safari and in Firefox too.